# Internal Server Error: No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, header, instagram-api

**status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error"
message: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.clone.instagram.authservice.fetchdata.model.Example] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]"**

So strangely this error has started showing up while accessing insta API,
What's strange is this happens "only sometimes",
And never happened before.
**It works some times, some times it pops this error**

```
const request = (options) => {
          const headers = new Headers();
        
          
            headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
          
        
          if (localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) {
            headers.append(
              "Authorization",
              "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
            );
          }
        
          const defaults = { headers: headers };
          options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);
        
          return fetch(options.url, options).then((response) =>
            response.json().then((json) => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(json);
              }
              return json;
            })
          );
        };
        
  export function registerInstaUserInfo(instaUserINfoRequest){
      if (!localStorage.getItem("accessToken")) {
        return Promise.reject("No access token set.");
      }
      
      console.log("inside getInstaUserInfo request ");
      return request({
        url: properties.INSTA_USER_REGISTER ,
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(instaUserINfoRequest),
      });
    }
    
  const getInstaUserInfoFromService = (response) => {
        //store respose.data
        if (response.data.user_id) {
          console.log("setting up insta user staate ", response.data);
          localStorage.setItem("insta_user", response.data);
          cookies.set("insta_user", response.data, { path: "/" });
          console.log("cookies ", cookies.get("insta_user"));
          const fb_access_token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
          console.log("fb_access_token", fb_access_token);
          const user_info = registerInstaUserInfo(response.data)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              setLinkedInstaAccounts([...linkedAccounts, res]);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error("Hello stackoverlflowpeople this is where error happens", err));
    
          console.log("user_info", user_info);
          props.history.push("/home");
          //redirecting to account.js
          // props.history.push("/me");
        }
      };
    
  const successResponse = (code) => {
        console.log("inside success func");
        console.log(code);
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append("redirect_uri", properties.INSTA_REDIRECT_URL);
        bodyFormData.append("code", code);
        bodyFormData.append("client_id", properties.INSTA_CLIENT_ID);
        bodyFormData.append("client_secret", properties.INSTA_CLIENT_SECRECT);
        bodyFormData.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: properties.INSTA_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
          data: bodyFormData,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Accept: "application/vnd.api+json",
          },
        })
          .then(getInstaUserInfoFromService)
          .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
          });
      };
    
    
    ----
    //component
      <InstagramLogin
            clientId={properties.INSTA_CLIENT_ID}
            buttonText="Login"
            redirectUri={properties.INSTA_REDIRECT_URL}
            scope="user_profile,user_media"
            onSuccess={successResponse}
            onFailure={failedresponseInstagram}
          />
```

=====================THIS getInstaUserFromService is where error happens

```
const getInstaUserInfoFromService = (response) => {
        //store respose.data
        if (response.data.user_id) {
          console.log("setting up insta user staate ", response.data);
          localStorage.setItem("insta_user", response.data);
          cookies.set("insta_user", response.data, { path: "/" });
          console.log("cookies ", cookies.get("insta_user"));
          const fb_access_token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
          console.log("fb_access_token", fb_access_token);
          const user_info = registerInstaUserInfo(response.data)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              setLinkedInstaAccounts([...linkedAccounts, res]);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error("Hello stackoverlflowpeople this is where error happens", err));
    
          console.log("user_info", user_info);
          props.history.push("/home");
          //redirecting to account.js
          // props.history.push("/me");
        }
      };
```

I was using this but I have not touched headers or anything, is it something with Instagram server?

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Comment: Done, but believe me I saw git history and I have never touched the API functions,It used to work fine, only recently it just just started happening "sometimes" and "sometimes" it just works

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to make your requests as "clean" as possible. Don't add headers you don't need for instance. A clash of `Accept` and `Content-Type` seems to be the cause of the issue apparently.

Comment: "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
Accept: "application/vnd.api+json",

You mean this, when making this request, there was no error tho but still I tried removing headers, didn't work the main problem is in registerInstaUserInfo, that's where the promise is rejected

Comment: The multipart header is definitely necessary. The error message sounds like Insta wants to send back HTML, something that shouldn't be the case with a REST API usually. Also, the fact that it tries to send back an instance of `model.Example` sounds fishy to me. Maybe contact their dev support?

Comment: Yes maybe because, I switched to an earlier commit when I never found this error, The same error persists

Comment: Yeah, an error 500 should basically never happen, regardless of how malformed the input might be.

Comment: lol, funny part, when i will come back tomorrow and try to login, it would work, but after 2 logins , it throws this error, weird

Comment: Is it possible that your App has exceeded its daily requests or something?

Comment: Not that I know of :/., might be but I logged into Insa only twice before this error comes